# How Do I Get HTTP Header Values From Coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion

How can I get HTTP Header values from Coldfusion?

(ColdFusion version: 6.2..)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the answer here in this post:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1425-Getting-Header-Values-From-A-ColdFusion-Request.htm

"Ben Nadel" had a great answer in there.

Similar example:

```
someVariable = getHttpRequestData().headers["User-Agent"];
```

Comment: +1 good job answering your own question :). You should click the check box next to it as well.

Comment: Thanks!  I will when it lets me in two days.  :)